# Python Pandas maximum of rows by element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe like

```
1 21
1 34
1 25 
2 43
3 32
3 47
4 39
4 31
```

and I want to find the maximum of all elements by first row element, i.e. I want a new datframe that looks something like this:

```
1 34
2 43
3 47
4 39
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `df[df['Value']==df['Value'].max()]` ?

Comment: df.groupby('Left value')['Right value'].max()?